# How to convert from (.lib) to (.dll) with OpenCV

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, dll

I am building a c++ code and I am using OpenCV2 static lib (.h and .hpp files), when I compiled it as a "Static library (.lib)" it build successfully and generate a .lib, and .obj files.

Now I am trying to use the previous project (c++) in c# project, so I tried to re-compile the c++ project by using "Dynamic Library (.dll)", but I get about 54 errors like this:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::_InputArray::empty(void)const
```

I tried to change the MDd to MTd, but it did not work too...

So, what's the best way to use the  c++ code in c# code, in that case !

Comment: tried using emugucv ?
its a sister library for opencv in c#

Comment: I finished the project, and it will take much time to rebuild it again using emgu!!